# One verb, multiple subjects, and multiple objects

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-patterns

Are the following constructions valid in English where we have a common verb with many subjects and objects? If yes, how do we usually phrase such sentences?

Lisa, US; Andrew, Mexico; and Taylor lives in Britain.

OR

Lisa US, Andrew Mexico, and Taylor lives in Britain.

I have searched the internet, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Hello, Andy. There are actually multiple subjects here, and the omission of a common verb is known as gapping (see [Nordquist at ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-gapping-1690885)). I've not come across verb deletion where the verb is put after any but the first subject: << Lisa lives in the US, Andrew in  Mexico, and Taylor in Britain. >> If you want to delete further (I wouldn't), << Lisa lives in the US; Andrew,  Mexico; and Taylor, Britain. >>

Comment: As Ross pointed out in ["Gapping and the Order of Constituents"](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/GappingandtheOrder.pdf), right-branching languages like English gap to the right (delete all but the **first** of a series), while left-branching languages like Japanese gap to the left (delete all but the **last** of a series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to omit a repeated element in a series, it is included in the first conjunct and can then be omitted in later ones (where allowed). For example:

> Lisa lives in the U.S.; Andrew, in Mexico; and Taylor, in Britain.

By the way, you could also repeat the subject, e.g.:

> Lisa lives in the U.S., works in Mexico, and vacations in Britain.

The adverbial phrase can't be omitted entirely if it's repeated, but it can be replace by what is essentially a pro-form:

> Lisa lives in the U.S., Andrew works there, and Taylor vacations there.

Comment: Can you please specify when it's not allowed? Moreover, do we have to include the preposition after every subsequent case, or can we omit that as well?

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Andy2000 The preposition can be omitted, since it's also repeated. I'll edit now to give an example of when omitting elements is not allowed.